# How can I implement like iOS twitter client profile collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

How can I implement like following profile view?
I want to know how menu and bottom's scrollView and collectionView are creating?
when it works smoothly vertical, I thought I needed to set them inside of long scrollView though.
Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: It's unclear, I don't understand which part you are refering too. There are plenty of CocoaPods/CocoaControls/GitHub that should already mimic some part.

Comment: I'm refering to seamless scroll with menu and bottom's collectionview. which library are you talking about? please teach me if you know @Larme

Comment: I don't understand. I see a Tab Bar at the bottom of the screen, a UITableView for the tweet listing, maybe a UICollectionView for the sections.